# Strange slowdown in some simple scala code

Tags: scala

I am processing a large number of records (CDRS) that are essentially (who, where, how much), to save space I use a lookup to map the strings into integer and aggregate the traffic on a map of maps (who maps to a map (where maps how much)

```
type CDR      = (String, String, Int)
type Lookup   = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, (Int, Float)]
type Traffic  = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int]]enter code here
```

I have found a strange behavior, when I build the lookup tables in advance the code runs as expected, however when I start processing and build the maps on the fly it slows down as it processes the records.

I use the same function to build the lookup tables for this comparison. I essentially check if the code for the lookup is there, if not i create a new entry (it is a mutable map), like this:

```
def index(id: String, map: Lookup, reverse: Reverse): Int = {
    if (map.contains(id)) {
        map(id)._1
    } else {
        val number = if (map.keys.size == 0) 0 else reverse.keys.max + 1
        reverse += ( number -> id)
        map += (id -> (number, 0.toFloat))
        number   
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here? 
EDIT----> I can no longer reproduce the slowdown. I will assume I was either too tired or dumber than usual. Running time now seems to be same as I expected to be.

Comment: Not sure what surprises you ... Building lookup tables as you go is slower than ... well ... not building them :)

Comment: Because i actually build them. I execute exactly the same instructions. I insert the same number of entries into the lookup tables.

Comment: You are talking about two _different_ cases, but saying you execute exactly the same instructions. If instructions are the same, so are the cases.

Comment: The order of execution was different. But lets forget, I can no longer reproduce the slowdown. They run now in exactly the same time either filling the look up table up front or filling on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

What is `mapCellRvs`? Default scala `Map`'s `.size` (and `.keys.size`, which is the same thing) simply counts all elements by scanning them linearly.

Try replacing `mapCellRvs.keys.size == 0` with `mapCellRvs.isEmpty` ...

Also, `reverse.keys.max` is linear as well. You may want to just remember the max somewhere separately, rather than compute it every time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i used a mutable variable before but you know, mutability, sin,... those things. But then it is linear when i build the lookup table before processing the records or I build as I go.

Comment: Mutable map is no less "sinful" then a mutable variable. More so if anything.

Comment: I know, I know... but for this I am afraid i have no other choice (I need to aggregate some billons rows) Not using a var is my penance :)

Comment: Ok, I am not religious, so ... If you have more questions about scala, let me know.

Comment: I have tried to use inmutable as much as possible and I have hit the wall now. I had a first, iterative, solution using several mutable trees. Now I have a recursive one with just one mutable map with essentially no loss of performance. I will open a new question for that. Thanks a lot for your help!